# Book including a computer game

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book (or had it read to me at school) a long time ago - probably around 15 years ago.

Points I recall

- The woman/mother and her child are driving somewhere to visit family, and the road is new, and she swerves for no reason. Turns out the road had been built over an old canyon (?) area where her brother had gone missing as a teenager years before.
- I think her brother was socially challenged of some sort, and was sometimes strange, when he had gone missing he was presumed to have died in that location, and I think he had been being bullied.
- The child gets a computer game, and when you enter it is set in the house. The mother is shocked because the hallway is identical to one in a house where she is sure only her brother and her would know exactly what that looked like, there were specific tiles I think. I feel like the game progresses and has many things that only the brother/her would know. I also could be wrong about it being the mother’s brother… the missing boy could have been the child’s brother/mother’s son?
- I think it was part of the twist, that the brother had actually been alive this whole time and was the one to create the game, they someone figure that out and use the game to find him?

Comment: Are there any fantasy or sci-fi aspects? If not, this might be a better match for the Literature SE.